# What is "Fix geometries" tool actually doing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geometry, qgis-processing, invalid-data

Sometimes geometry's have to be fixed for further processing. So you can use ["Fix geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries) and it will do the job for you without prompting. But I'm wondering, what the tool "Fix geometries" is really doing.

What kind of geometry errors is it fixing?

Comment: QGIS is open source. Have you looked at the source code to review what it's doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [OGC Simple Feature Access](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa) specification, geometries need to follow the *OpenGIS* compliance (see the [PostGIS docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity) for quick reference), where (listing only the most prominent predicates)

- **Points** are considered *inherently valid*
- **LineStrings** are valid if they are ***simple***, meaning that they don't pass an inner vertex twice
- **Polygons** are ***valid*** if their linear components are ***simple*** and none of their rings cross
- **MultiPoints** are ***valid*** if no coordinate pair is present twice
- **MultiLineStrings** are ***simple*** if all their components are ***simple***, and common vertices only *touch*
- **MultiPolygons** are ***valid*** if all their components are ***valid*** and do not *overlap*

In order to do so, the internally called *GEOS* modules will (listing only the most prominent operations)

- correctly *node* a **LineString** and remove consecutive duplicated vertices
- correctly *node* the linear components of a **Polygon** and iteratively rebuild all possible ***valid*** areas from them
- do the above for all parts of their **Multi** geometries

where *noding* means breaking apart a linear component at *non-consecutive* duplicated vertices.

In this context, 'fixing' geometries rather means creating the maximal set of their ***valid*** and/or ***simple*** parts, and may result in a collection of geometries of different dimensionality.

Answer (score 5):

I think [@Vince's idea](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378154/what-is-fix-geometry-actually-doing-in-qgis#comment618012_378154) is what you can try.

From the [QGIS Documetation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries):

> Attempts to create a valid representation of a given invalid geometry
> without losing any of the input vertices. Already valid geometries are
> returned without further intervention. Always outputs multi-geometry
> layer.

More details you can find in:

- [qgsalgorithmfixgeometries.h](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmfixgeometries.h)
- [qgsalgorithmfixgeometries.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmfixgeometries.cpp)

---

**References:**

- [GitHub/QGIS/src/analysis/processing/](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/analysis/processing)

Answer (score 5):

It is basically fixing your geometry using the `makeValid` method, that is, correcting your geometry without loosing nodes:

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html?highlight=qgsgeometry#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.makeValid

similar of the `St_MakeValid` of PostGIS:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html